# php dynamic dropdown box value selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a dropdown box that gets its content from a view in mysql. The drop down results are fetched and displayed properly when I view this form. When I select a value in the dropdown box and hit the submit button a blank row is added to my destination table. I want the selected value from the dropdown box to be added to another mysql table. The dropdown selected value is not being passed to batch_number_add.php, this file is executing and inserting a blank line into the destination table. How can I make this work?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="batch_number_add.php" type="post">
<?php 
$query = "SELECT batch_number, batch_number  FROM new_order_count_view";
include 'batch_module_connect.php'; 
$result = $conn->query($query);
?>
<select>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    echo '<option value="'.$row["batch_number"].'">'.$row["batch_number"].'</option>';
?>
<input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Silly question: Why are you selecting `batch_number` twice in the query?

Comment: I would show `batch_number_add.php` as well as you obviously have done something wrong in there as well. You need to test for valid input before attempting to store anything to the database

Answer (score 2):

First, you didn't give a name to your `select` tag.

```
<select name="thenamehere">...

<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row["batch_number"].'">'.$row["batch_number"].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Then, at the end of the loop injecting the `option`, close the `select` tag.
Your target file should then have the value of your select.

I also suggest to add braces around the `echo` which stands in the `while` loop

Comment: That's not necessary, was just making a suggestion to add { and } for the `while` control structure

Comment: Ahh, got ya, For future reference they are called braces `{}`